# Getting selected Radiobutton values into the Struts2 Action class

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

I'm getting values of question and selected answers from radio button to JavaScript and storing those values in two arrays. I need to pass these two arrays into the struts2 action class and to store.

#### JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var nameArry = [];
     var i=0;
     var count=[];
    function handler(_this) {  


                var qno_name=_this.name;
                var id=qno_name.substring(1);

                  var qid=$("#id"+id).val();
                  //alert("qid"+qid)

        var ans=_this.value;
        nameArry[i]=ans;
                // alert(ans);   
                  // alert(nameArry[i]);



            count[i]=qid;
        i=i+1;
        /* document.write(nameArry);
        alert(nameArry); */
        //  
    }

  </script>
```

#### JSP code:

```
 <table id="employeelist" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">

                                <tr>
                                    <th>SL.No</th>
                                    <th>Question</th>
                                    <th>QID</th>
                                    <th>Very Little Like Me</th>
                                    <th>A Little Like Me</th>
                                    <th>Like Me</th>
                                    <th>A Lot Like Me</th>


                                </tr>

                                <tbody>  
                                    <tr>
                                        <%
                                            int i = 0;  
                                        %>
                                <s:form action="LearningModalityResultAction">     



                                    <s:iterator value="lModlity" status="var"  var="true"  id="IM">


                                        <%i++;%>
                                        <td><s:property value="#var.index+1"/></td>   
                                        <td><s:property value="modalityquestName"/></td>
                                         <td><s:property  value="moadlityquestionId"/></td>



<!--                                        <td class="hidden-480"><select name="r<%=i%>" contenteditable="2" id="MySelectOption"  onchange="handler();" >
                                                <option value="1" selected>1</option>
                                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                                <option value="4">4</option>  
                                            </select>-->
                                            <span class="lbl"></span>
                                            <s:hidden   name="modalityquestName" value="%{modalityquestName}" id="id%{#var.index+1}"/>

                                            <td class="hidden-480"><input name="r<%=i%>" value="1"   type="radio" onclick="handler(this)" />  
                                                     <span class="lbl"></span>
                                                       </label></td>
                                            <td class="hidden-480"><input name="r<%=i%>" value="2"  type="radio" onclick="handler(this)"/>
                                                        <span class="lbl"></span>
                                                  </label></td>
                                            <td class="hidden-480"><input name="r<%=i%>" value="3"    type="radio" onclick="handler(this)"/>
                                                        <span class="lbl"></span>
                                                  </label></td>
                                            <td class="hidden-480"><input name="r<%=i%>" value="4"     type="radio"  onclick="handler(this)"/>      
                                                        <span class="lbl"></span>
                                                  </label></td> 

                                        </tr>
                                        </tr>
                                        </tr>

                                    </s:iterator> 

                                    <div class="form-actions">
<!--                                        <button class="btn btn-success">Save</button>-->
<s:submit value="Save" action="LearningModalityResultAction"></s:submit>
                                        <button class="btn" type="reset">
                                            <i class="icon-undo bigger-110"></i>
                                            Reset</button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-info" type="button">
                                            <i class=""></i>
                                            Cancel  </button>

                                    </div>

                                </s:form>
                                </tbody>

                            </table>
```

Comment: you wanted to make intration between javascript and java?

Comment: yes, nameArry[i] and count[i] these two array need to pass in action(java) class

Comment: you can use DWR for that,which will pass your data to java class

Comment: you should map the form to the action, where's your action code?

Comment: In action class I created  setters and getters with those array names and getting those values with request.getparameter().. still m getting null values....can anyone please give me a example code to write in struts2 action class...

Comment: @A5l-lE5 Hi you have mentioned DWR. can you post any example code to use DWR to get radio button values in java class..

Comment: do you have any idea about usign DWR ?

Comment: Why do you want to store them in javascript array and not submitted from form directly to action?

Answer (score 2):

I tried same thing with checkboxes, i hope it might work for radio buttons as well.

First you need to create an instance *HttpServletRequest* request on Action class with getters and setters. Now in you view page(jsp or html) give your radiobutton a name, like myRadioButtons.

Now in action class, 
*String[] checkedBoxes = request.getParameterValues("myRadioButtons");*

Now on above array you should get arrays of values with 1s and 0s.